# Nuitka compilation error when building on windows

Tags: python, nuitka

I have a python project I'd like to package up as a standalone executable. I have tried PyInstaller but with little luck. So I tried Nuitka instead. Everything seems to work fine (Pass 1 and Pass 2) but when it comes to compiling the generated C code I keep getting the same Fatal Error below.

```
Nuitka:INFO: Completed Python level compilation and optimization.
    Nuitka:INFO: Generating source code for C backend compiler.
    Nuitka:INFO: Running data composer tool for optimal constant value handling.
    Nuitka:INFO: Running C compilation via Scons.
    Nuitka-Scons:INFO: Backend C compiler: cl (cl 14.3).
    FATAL: Error, the Windows SDK must be installed in Visual Studio.
```

I tried, as advised on the Nuitka homepage to install the latest version of Visual Studio in order to get the latest MSVC (v14.3). Apparently, I need a compiler that compiles C11 (which 14.3 should do).I did all this and still I get the same Fatal Error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try a different compiler? Personally I use [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) (which [can be installed using MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-cmake?view=msvc-170)), as I went through all available options trying to avoid false positives in anti-virus programs, which for some reason were detecting trojans in the generated .exe files - clang produces an executable that's most compliant with those programs (VirusTotal results for [mingw](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/8ca6101378fbec7bddfd7917ca1d5de5e40d95d5b75ea39fe609b5c30bc01f92?nocache=1) and [clang](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/bf7a3971eb2bea60f3b22c4e2a19490e9b552c8424913e57e0a419c22549131b?nocache=1)). Once you've installed it all you gotta do is pass `--clang` argument to Nuitka.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with setting up Clang for Nuitka, this is the bare minimum you have to do in order to get it working. You either need to have Visual Studio with C++ support installed (providing `cl.exe`), or you would install just the bare minimum, which would take approx. 13 GB of your disk space:

- Go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ and under `Tools for Visual Studio` download & run `Build Tools for Visual Studio`.
- Under `Individual components` tab find & install:

  - `MSVC vXXX - VS YYYY C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest)`,
  - `C++ Clang compiler for Windows`,
  - `Windows 11 SDK`.

The first one provides 'cl.exe', the second one provides 'clang-cl.exe'.
After installation, you need to run `Visual Studio` / `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS`.
To make sure 'cl.exe' is reachable, just run:

```
cl
```

To make sure 'clang-cl.exe' is targeting x64 architecture, run:

```
clang-cl -v
```

Then, continue with Nuitka (`py -m nuitka --clang ...`).